# What if I provide different executors for thenApplyAsync and supplyAsync?

Tags: java, completable-future

Let's say I am creating async tasks by using `supplyAsync` method, and using executor E1 for this.

Then for `thenApply` or `thenApplyAsync` the executor I supply is E2.

How will `thenApply` use E1 and E2? Which executor will it prioritize?

Comment: You can not specify an executor for `thenApply`. When you specify E2 for `thenApplyAsync`, of course, it will use E2 for the function provided to `thenApplyAsync`. So it’s not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `thenApply` stage may run in calling thread if it can be started at time of executing the `thenApply`, otherwise when not completed at that moment it should run in the thread of the preceding executing task.

You can demonstrate with:

```
Function<String,String> func = s -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" "+s);
    return s;
};

ExecutorService exec1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
ExecutorService exec2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
Future<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> func.apply("ONE"), exec1)
                         .thenApplyAsync(s -> func.apply("TWO:"+s), exec2)
                         .thenApply(s -> func.apply("THREE:"+s));

System.out.println("f.get()="+f.get());
```

This should print the threads used. If run this a few times you may see alternate handling for step 3. Both thread pools are used for steps 1/2 and if the action is quick either the calling thread is used for step 3 (main in this case).

```
Thread[#20,pool-1-thread-1,5,main] ONE
Thread[#21,pool-2-thread-1,5,main] TWO:ONE
Thread[#1,main,5,main] THREE:TWO:ONE
f.get()=THREE:TWO:ONE
```

or it may print that it used the preceding executor service - as for step 2.

```
Thread[#20,pool-1-thread-1,5,main] ONE
Thread[#21,pool-2-thread-1,5,main] TWO:ONE
Thread[#21,pool-2-thread-1,5,main] THREE:TWO:ONE
f.get()=THREE:TWO:ONE
```

If you add a `sleep` to the task step, you are likely to see the latter only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be executed on the pool you explicitly set, no magic:

```
ExecutorService pool1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, r -> new Thread(r, "t1"));
ExecutorService pool2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2, r -> new Thread(r, "t2"));

Runnable sleep = () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
};

System.out.println("Result 1: " + CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool1)
    .thenApply(it -> {
        return it + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }).join()
);
System.out.println("Result 2: " + CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        sleep.run();
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool1)
    .thenApply(it -> {
        sleep.run();
        return it + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }).join()
);

System.out.println("Result 3: " + CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool1)
    .thenApplyAsync(it -> {
        return it + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool2)
    .join()
);

System.out.println("Result 4: " + CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        sleep.run();
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool1)
    .thenApplyAsync(it -> {
        sleep.run();
        return it + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }, pool2)
    .join()
);

pool1.shutdownNow();
pool2.shutdownNow();
```

Output:

```
Result 1: t1, main // OR `Result 1: t1, t1` if you are unlucky enough
Result 2: t1, t1
Result 3: t1, t2
Result 4: t1, t2
```

The only interesting thing here is behaviour of the completed futures. Completed future would NOT pass its executor down the chain, so if pool is not configured explicitly (`Result 1`) chain may run on the current thread.

Comment: Now try without the `sleep` call…

Comment: I didn't get your point... `Result 1` and `Result 3` do run without `sleep` call

Comment: I didn’t claim that they wouldn’t. What’s the purpose of those `sleep` calls?

Comment: without `sleep` created completable future could be resolved before `.thenApply` and `.thenApplyAsync` are invoked - effectively it's the same as `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(...)`. and no task executor would be passed down the chain

Comment: So they *do* have an effect and trying without the `sleep` calls will have interesting results? However, your explanation does not cover the `sleep` calls within functions passed to the `.thenApply[Async]`. And well, “if you are unlucky enough”, an arbitrary `sleep` call does not guaranty that the timing is as intended, so Result 2 still could be “t1, main”…

Comment: By the way, the implementation never passes down an executor, it just happens to execute dependent actions in the current thread. You’ll notice the difference when using `Executor e = r -> { System.out.println("hello"); new Thread(r).start(); }` for the `supplyAsync` stage. This executor is never used for the chained `thenApply` stages.